# How to Copy a Folder(Not File by File) from server to Android Device

Tags: java, android

I want to copy a folder from server which contains many files but without traveling through files in that folder. 
  I have URL of that folder and i want to copy that folder from web service.
Is this possible? if yes then please explain?

Comment: I think it is not possible. If you can zip the folder on the server then you could. But if it is in folder form I think you'll have to traverse each of the files.

Comment: ziping a folder is a very good approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.   You can either created an archive (zip, tar, etc.) of the folder on the server using some script and then download the archive, or you can recursively traverse the folder and request all of the files individually.  I'd strongly recommend the archive option, as recursive file traversal over HTTP could be extremely messy.  Depending on your skill and level of control, you could create a URL path that triggers a small script to archive the folder and then initializes a download of the newly created archive.  That might be slow, but it will give you a "live" copy of the folder content at all times.